# Description does not show in the right position

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a grid of images like this:

```
<div class="city-container container" id="popupContainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-33">
        <img  src="img/images/opera.jpg" ng-click="showTabDialogOpera($event)"/>
          <div class="description" style="font-size: 8pt"><strong>Opera de Lyon</strong></div>
     </div>

    <div class="col col-33">
      <img  src="img/Image1.jpg" ng-click="showTabDialogBasilique($event)"/>
      <div class="description" style="font-size: 8pt"><strong>Basilique de Fourvière</strong></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-33">
      <img  src="img/images/hoteldeville.jpg" ng-click="showTabDialogHotel($event)"/>
      <div class="description" style="font-size: 8pt"><strong>Hotel de villde de Lyon</strong></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the description does not show in the right position.

**CSS:**

```
.city-container .description {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.6);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

If you want the description to show up next to the image, try relpacing

```
position: absolute;
```

with

```
display: inline-block;
```

**Update**
I have updated the CSS. Sorry for the delay.

I scaled the image to fit the width of the column. Hope that meets your requirement.

```css
.col-33 {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.col-33 img {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-33 .description {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center; 
  padding: 5px 0px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="city-container container" id="popupContainer">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-33">
        <img  src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/00cf75/fff.png&text=IMG" ng-click="showTabDialogOpera($event)"/>
          <div class="description" style="font-size: 8pt"><strong>Opera de Lyon</strong></div>
     </div>

    <div class="col col-33">
      <img  src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/00cf75/fff.png&text=IMG" ng-click="showTabDialogBasilique($event)"/>
      <div class="description" style="font-size: 8pt"><strong>Basilique de Fourvière</strong></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-33">
      <img  src="http://dummyimage.com/150x50/00cf75/fff.png&text=IMG" ng-click="showTabDialogHotel($event)"/>
      <div class="description" style="font-size: 8pt"><strong>Hotel de villde de Lyon</strong></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: inline-block puts the description after the picture. What i want to do is align it at the end (on top of it) of each picture.

Comment: I updated my question with a picture so you can see the problem. The description is not ON the photos